# Rounding vs truncation in Math class in Java

Tags: numbers

At present I am doing this:

```
long x = Math.round((numberFormat(Collections.min(tempList)) * 1000) / 1000);
```

In the above statement `tempList` is `List` type. Suppose `Collections.min(tempList)` returns the value 236.589; `x` is assigned the value 237, but I want 236 only.

How do I do that?

Comment: Please read this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use the [floor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor%28double%29)-method instead of round.